# Determining correct angle of rotation from $arccos$ and $arcsin$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, rotations

I'm running into a trigonometry wall in my Linear Algebra class.  I'm given a transformation matrix that represents a rotation, and am asked to find the angle of rotation.

[image]

I know that the $\cos\theta = -0.8$ and that $\sin\theta = 0.6$.  I should be able to find the answer through either $\arccos(-0.8)$ or $\arcsin(0.6)$, but they give me different answers.  How would I be able to determine which one is the right one?  I remember that $\arccos$ is defined for $[0, \pi]$ and arcsin for $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, but don't see how to relate these to the right answer.   The answers in the back of the book state that the answer is 2.5 rad, which is given by $\arccos(-0.8)$, but I'm not sure why that answer is the correct one vs. $\arcsin(0.6) = 0.64$ rad.  Can someone help me understand the why one answer given is correct and the other one isn't?

Comment: In which quadrant is cosine negative and sine positive?

Comment: Of course!  Now I see it. Quadrant II.  Thank you!

Comment: $\sin\theta=0.6\to \theta_1=\arcsin 0.6;\;\theta_2=\pi-\arcsin 0.6$ as $\cos\theta_2=-0.8$ that is the solution $\pi-\arcsin 0.6$